# Is this correct : jquery is to javascript, django is to python?

Tags: frameworks

I'm familiar with jquery and javascript but i'm a python noob. Whenever I learn something about python on the web, there's mention of django here and there. When i went to the official django site, it described it as "Django is a high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design." So I inferred it's what jquery is for javascript, am I correct? 
[This might seem like a silly question but I tend to get shameless when it comes to asking questions on stack**overflow**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a very useful comparison.

JQuery is mostly a wrapper around core functionality of javascript. Partly to make it easier to use and partly because otherwise you'd have to deal with browser specific problems even for the most basic scripts.

Django is a full-featured web framework that has many useful and necessary things built-in. It has request routing, templating, database abstractions, localization and a lot more. 
In contrast to other web-frameworks it has those things tightly coupled and is opionated on what's the best practice to build your website with it.

A better comparison in the JavaScript world is (as an example) AngularJS. It also comes with lots of good features (routing, templating, data-bindings, dependency injection, etc.) but when you use it, you should better stick to "the angular way" of doing front-end JavaScript.

Think of JQuery more of a low-level library that you can build your code and even frameworks like AngularJS on. Kinda like the standard library of Python.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Kind of- it is in the sense that JQuery is essentially a set of useful bits of code written in Javascript and Django the same in Python. However, JQuery is a more functional framework, where as DJango is more like a CMS framework.

Answer (score 1):

No question is a silly question!

Almost, but not exactly.

I would say your python to javascript comparison is correct (as Python can be used as a scripting language for web applications, just like javascript), but jQuery is not exactly like Django.

jQuery is a library designed to simplify the scripts needed for dynamic website functionality, whereas Django is more useful in the creation of complex, database-driven websites.